# App stops when I click button to run main activity

Tags: android

Apparently I'm not calling MainActivity correctly but I don't understand why not

Here is the code:

```
fun playAgain() {
    btnPlayAgain.setOnClickListener{
    val intent = Intent("com.tjdroid.higherorlower.MainActivity}")
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Here is part of the logcat:

> 05-09 13:22:28.100 12373-12373/com.tjdroid.higherorlower
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.tjdroid.higherorlower, PID: 12373
>       android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.tjdroid.higherorlower.MainActivity} }

Comment: You specified the target activity as an action. Why not use `val intent = Intent(this@YourActivity, MainActivity::class.java)`?

Comment: Have you added the activity in Manifest file ?

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm using Kotlin so adding 'new' just causes an error.

I guess I don't understand why
 val intent = Intent("com.tjdroid.higherorlower.CorrectGuessActivity")
        startActivity(intent)

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm using Kotlin so adding 'new' just causes an error.

I guess I don't understand why
 val intent = Intent("com.tjdroid.higherorlower.CorrectGuessActivity")
works and 
val intent = Intent("com.tjdroid.higherorlower.MainActivity}")
doesn't

My manifest looks like this
        <activity android:name=".CorrectGuessActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name = "com.tjdroid.higherorlower.CorrectGuessActivity"/>
            <category android:name = "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong constructor. [Using `new Intent(String)` creates the intent with a given action, but the activity name is not an action](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(java.lang.String)).

You need to use the constructor [`new Intent(Context, Class<?>)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E)).

For example,

```
val intent = Intent(this@CurrentActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

For starting an Activity you have to provide source and destination. Source is your current Activity and destination is MainActivity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct constructor.

Intent intent =new Intent(context,Destination class)

Ex: Intent intent =new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,DestinationActivity.class)

Answer (score -1):

As you error says  No Activity found to handle Intent. First check Manifest if you have added the activity or not.

Secondly pass the required parameters in [intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) as below :

```
val intent = Intent(context, UserDetailActivity::class.java)
startActivity(Intent)
```